# uploading php script instead of chosen file

Tags: php, html, upload

I have two simple starter scripts (html and php) to choose a file from the machine and then upload to server. However when I press upload, it appears to be uploading the actual php script that deals with the upload. here they are:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

THis i'd imagine is just a silly mistake somewhere on my part, but this is my first experience in uploading a file using php. thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `it appears to be uploading the actual php script`, is the source of your script shown on the screen or are you seeing output of the script like `Upload: upload_file.php`, etc.?

Comment: i'm using google chrome, and the file which is downloading is the upload_file.php script.

Comment: please explain what is the problem?

Comment: problem: I am choosing a .txt file from my filesystem and uploading it. then chrome downloads the php script, not the .txt script.

Comment: What does your code to do the downloading look like?  Have you checked  your server to make sure the proper file was uploaded?

Comment: when viewing my localhost system logs on webmin i see no activity....

Comment: @brucezepplin is this the only `php script` on your server ? if not, are the other `php scripts` working ?